# How can I find the observations associated with rank j in this code?

Tags: r, set, sample, rank, sampling

I have been trying to find the observations associated with rank j in Ranked Set Sampling method. The problem is I don't know how to use the simulations to find the Xj values I'm supposed to work with further. Please help!

#The rankedsets function selects ranked sets from a target population. The selection of units in a set is without replacement, but the sets are selecting with replacement.

```
rankedsets<-function(X,m,s=m){
  if(s==m){
    x=sample(X,(m^2),replace=F)
    n=matrix(x,ncol=m,nrow=m,byrow=T)
    ms=matrix(0,ncol=m,nrow=m)
    
    
    for (i in 1:m){
      ms[i,]=sort(n[i,])
    }
    
    
  }else {
    x=sample(X,(m*s),replace=F)
    n=matrix(x,ncol=m,nrow=s,byrow=T)
    ms=matrix(0,ncol=m,nrow=s)
    for (i in 1:s){
      ms[i,]=sort(n[i,])
    }
  }
  
  
  
  return(ms)
}

#The rss function samples from a target population by using ranked set sampling method
rss<-function(X,m,r=1,sets=FALSE){
  
  rss=numeric()
  set=matrix(0,ncol=m,nrow=(m*r))
  if (is.vector(X)){
    a=0
    
    for (j in 1:r){
      ms=rankedsets(X,m)
      
      for (i in 1:(m)){
        set[i+a,]=ms[i,]
        rss[i+a]=ms[i,i]
      }
      
      a=a+m
    }
    
    rss=matrix(rss,ncol=m,nrow=r,byrow=T)
    cn=rn=numeric()
    for (i in 1:r){
      rn[i]=paste("r","=",i)
    }
    for (i in 1:m){
      cn[i]=paste("m","=",i)
    }
    rownames(rss)=rn
    colnames(rss)=cn
    
    if (sets){
      s=list(sets=set,sample=rss)
      return(s)
      
    } else {
      return(rss)}
    
  }else stop(" X must be a vector!",call.=F)
}

#RSS Data Generation
data=rnorm(10000,1,3)
rss(data,m=5,r=3,sets=TRUE)
```

I was trying using simulations but the code doesn't return Xj values:

```
sims = 1000
Xj = rep(NA, sims)
```

because I don't really know where I should put my for loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO Felix. Can you please share the expected output?

Comment: The output isn't set, it will change with the change in the values!